# UTF8 charecter printing to file in C

Tags: c, utf-8

ı am trying to learn coding c.
I want to print utf-8 charecter degree  °
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm

ı use lots of fprintf in code so if ı understood correctly ı cant use wide charecters or fwprintf.
with the code below ı get the result that ı wanted on my local Ubuntu machine but this code is

```
 fprintf(a,"\u00B0");
```

for lecture assigment and run on moodles vpl.

[image: ![enter image description here]

as you see in screen cast degree symbol is not printed.
so ı look for alternative approaches,saw at somewhere \u is compiler depended maybe thats the reason.
ı also tried

```
char b*={0xC2,0xB0,0};
fprintf(a,"%s",b);
```

didn't worked as ı expected 
looking for alternative approaches .

### Thank you.

### Your output:

537 172~38' 16.8012" E 43~31' 26.4002" S Christchurch New-Zealand 363926 74.05
536 171~12' 25.2015" E 42~28' 19.1967" S Greymouth New-Zealand 9419 182.24
538 170~28' 26.4155" E 45~53'  2.3925" S Dunedin New-Zealand 114347 240.97

---

### Expected output:

537 172° 38' 16.8012" E 43° 31' 26.4002" S Christchurch New-Zealand 363926 74.05
536 171° 12' 25.2015" E 42° 28' 19.1967" S Greymouth New-Zealand 9419 182.24
538 170° 28' 26.4155" E 45° 53'  2.3925" S Dunedin New-Zealand 114347 240.97

ı tried different methods and sometimes got the error;
when ı try to set locale to utf8encode or printf(\u00b0) 
cat: user.out.disp: No such file or directory

Comment: Would you be able to select with your mouse the text in your output and in expected output and copy and paste it here? A guess, try just `printf("°");`.

Comment: I tried and gaved same result. some unknown charecter like tilda and ı forget to mention that ı also tried printf("\xc2b0") and printf("\xc2\xb0") didn't worked out as well.

Comment: Could you paste the text in "Your output:" and "Expected output:" here on stackoverflow into your post?

Comment: It is difficult to help you if you don't follow the rule of SO to post condenst but complete code that shows the behavior. What is generally the problem here is the connection with your runtime. Usually you'd have to ensure that you have a UTF-8 locale *and* that you tell your C program to use it. Per default your program uses the C locale, which usually does not have UTF-8 support. To enable it you usually have to do something like `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` at the start of your program.